# Reverse number function in C

Tags: c, function, reverse

So if I input say 092, it does not return 290, instead returns 29 which is not what I want it to do. Any advice?

```
int reverseNumber(int number){
    int ans = 0;
    while(number > 0) {
        int rightDigit;
        rightDigit = number % 10;
        ans =ans *10 + rightDigit;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    return ans; 
}
```

Comment: Please post the function where you read the number from the user

Comment: So, don't treat it as a number.  `092` as a number is the same as `92`.  Instead, treat it as a string (character data).

Comment: You would probably have to send the string of the number, and not the number itself. Or have to specify the number of characters the number is, otherwise you can't distinguish between 092 and 0092.

Comment: The only integer that starts with a zero is `0`

Comment: @smac89 This is of course not true. 00777 starts with a zero, and it is an integer.

Comment: @DYZ 00777 is a representation of 777, the value of 0000777 is equivalent to 777, 000000777 is as much an integer as a picture is the object it depicts

Comment: @smac89 In the same spirit, a zero does not start with a 0, it _is_ a zero. "Starts" always refers to a linear representation.

Comment: @DYZ what does 0 start with?

Comment: @smac89 A number is a quantity. It does not 'start with.' But a _numerical representation_ of a zero starts with digit 0, and so does 0000777, which is one of the representations of 777.

Answer (score 4):

It is because `029` is no different from `29` decimal<sup>1</sup>. For this to work you need to take the input as a string instead, and invert the characters. After that you can convert the resulting string to a number.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>A leading 0 means it's an octal number, but in this particular case it has a 9 which is not an octal digit. Depending on how you convert from numbers to strings, this can be something to consider. But if you are just `scanf()`ing it, then it will be decimal for sure.</sub>

Comment: Does that mean I have to change my function's input to char instead of int?

Comment: @Anymee A char array.

Comment: oh man. I am a beginner who just started learning C a few days ago. I don't know what a char array is yet...

Comment: @Anymee An array of characters? Do you know what an array is?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 092 in int.

```
cin>>a;  //a=092
cout<<a; //it will print 92
```

So, you should take input as string and then you could reverse the string.